# Set $this in php to clicked element

Tags: php, this, getelementbyid

I am new to php & I don't know if this can be done, but since I already wrote the rest of the code, I am really hoping it can be. I have a php page that dynamically generates several tables/widgets. They are all the same widget, only difference is the id & the data. After the page has loaded, I want to do some data collection on only the clicked table. Regardless of what widget I modify or click, '$this' is always referencing the first widget. Is there a way to set '$this' in php to reference whichever instance of the widget is clicked? (I can't use DOMDocument because I have no html pae to load. It is all generated by php) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No. `$this` is reserved and can *only* be used to refer to an object instance from within itself.

eg:

```
class Foo {

  public function construct() {
    $this->arg = 'bar'; // legal
  }

}

$this = 'baz'; // illegal
```

You also seem to be missing the point that PHP and Javascript run **completely and entirely separately**. PHP runs on the web server to generate the page, Javascript runs inside the browser after the finished page has been delivered to the browser.

The only way to communicate between JS in the browser and PHP on the server is through AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

The `$this` variable refers to the object itself when using it from inside a class method so no, this can't be changed. You need to alter your code so that every widget has it's own object.